# What is 'call' meaning in JDBC callable statement?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have faced this question in interview. What is call in JDBC callable statement. I know it is not key word.

For example we have following code

```
String SQL = "{call getEmpName (?, ?)}";  
cstmt = conn.prepareCall (SQL);
```

what is call in the first statement represents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call` is used to execute a database stored procedure. Then, it's followed by the name of the stored procedure and parameters. In fact, this is how the SQL statement generally looks:

```
"{ ? = call getEmpName (?, ?)}"
```

Where the first parameter belongs to the output result from the stored procedure (if defined). If the stored procedure doesn't return any data, then this parameter can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Luiggi, but how JVM will treat this 'call'? like is it a static member of any class?

Comment: @rajesh that's not job of the JVM. For the JVM, it's a `String`. The JDBC driver and the proper database are the real actors in this use case.

Comment: @ Luiggi Thanks for Clarificatoin